# Use .razor pages in a web application from a Razor component library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a Razor class library that has `cshtml` pages and i am trying to convert the pages to .razor pages.

On .net 7 I tryed in an empty solution following the doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

I added the two templates and everythyng works as expected and i can browse the `Page1.cshtml` added from the template, but if I add, in the same path of `Page1.cshtml` the razor component `Test.razor`, I add to it the page directive `@page "/test"` and try to browse to https://localhost:7054/myfeature/test I get a 404, why?

Is it possible to consume .razor pages from a web application?

This is my services configuration :

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
```

I also tryed to add

```
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

and

```
    app.MapBlazorHub();
```

without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get a 404, why?

You should make sure blazor server works well on your side first, all your razor components was rendered on `_Host.cshtml` by default.this line is required(it maps all routes that don't match your razor page routes to _Host.cshtml,without it you would get 404 err):

```
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

and check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/project-structure?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-server) if you missed something else  required ,such as `App.razor`

When it comes to consume ASP.NET Core Razor components from RCL,you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I tried as below on myside:

[image]

[image]

codes in conponents1 of RCL proj:

```
<div class="my-component">
    This component is defined in the <strong>RCL</strong> library.
</div>
```

codes in RCLComponent.razor in BalzorServerRCL proj:

```
@page "/RCLComponent"
<RCL.Component1 />
```

It works:

[image]

Comment: So, the key is the put App.razor file that do all the route mapping work, and add  MapFallbackToPage to web application, in this way the other library that encaplulate the first library seems not needed, Also, If I want to use the library from a blazor server app, I have just to add AdditionalAssemblies to its(blazor server application) App.razor and all seems work. Thank You